# Spring @TestPropertySource classpath vs file

Tags: java, spring

Is there way to load test properties like this?

```
@TestPropertySource("${test.config:'classpath:application.test.properties'}")
```

The point is to check test.config argument (there could be something like *file:c:/test.properties*) and if the value is not set, then it will take default properties from classpath.

I was able to load properties from classpath swithing it using argument.

**I was unable to combine classpath and file**

**Solved:**

```
@PropertySource(value = {"classpath:application.test.properties","${test.config}"}, ignoreResourceNotFound = true)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- if environment variable test.config is not defined then context will
  not be loaded
- if environment variable test.config is defined but file
  test.properties is not present then also context will  loaded.

I think you are not using `TestPropertySource` as per it's use case.

`TestPropertySource` is used if you want to override some properties during test cases. If you want to override some properties in test cases, just  put those properties in test property file. 
Spring will override only those properties which are there in in test property file

Not sure why you want to check test.config environment variable and then do some operations .

Comment: The point is to have default test properties, that could be overridden per various environments.

Comment: this is needed for Unit testing or for actual code ?

Comment: Then you need to create different profiles in Maven as per environments,  you can use maven-surefire-plugin to set environment variable. in maven profile set environment  variable as per your need .

Comment: Found a solution using @PropertySource(value = {"classpath:application.test.properties","${test.config}"}, ignoreResourceNotFound = true)